# transparant 360 image is displayed black

Tags: javascript, html, css

We want to use a program that automaticly sets 24 pictures in a 360 script. 
The program is very easy (maybe to easy) Because after putting the transparant png images in this program, the output is nothing more than:

a pop-up:

```
<a width="224" height="330" href="https://embed.imajize.com/2544759" target="imajize" onclick="window.open(this.href,'imajize','width='+this.getAttribute('width')+',height='+this.getAttribute('height')+',scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,status=no,resizable=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,top=10,left=10');">360° View</a>
```

or an iframe:

```
<iframe width="224" height="330" src="https://embed.imajize.com/2544759" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

is there someone who can find the solution for this weird problem?

Comment: Share the code with us please

Comment: Hi these are the codes;

Comment: Can you also tell what script this is?

Comment: This is an iframe as you see. It loads the https://embed.imajize.com/2544759.

@Mark, I added an answer you should do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
body {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

or this:

```
body
{
    background:none transparent;
}
```

Also try adding `allowtransparency="true"` as parameter for the iframe.

Comment: Hi @antonelli, at first, thanks for your prompt reply. Unfortunately it still shows a black instead of transparant background. I have now placed it like this in my site '(body {
    background: transparent !important;
}

<iframe width="224" height="330" src="https://embed.imajize.com/2544759" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0;" allowfullscreen allowtransparency="true" </iframe>'

Comment: @MarkGubbels , you need to add the body definition inside a <style> tag like this:
<style>
body {
    background: transparent !important;
}</style>

or directly in a separate css file

Comment: There are images in the iframe. On the image, there is a chair and a black background. It is in the picture. You can't handle the black background, which is in the image. You must modify the images itself.

Comment: @DiabloSteve lol you're right, i've checked the source on the page, and it shows an image with black bg.

Comment: Yeah, but nice try @L. Antonelli. If there is other black background elsewhere, you example can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make it transparent with css, nor js. This is a picture rotator. The picture with the chair has black background. If you de the DOM. The picture has black background.

If you can modify the picture itself, change the black to transparent in it.